# axios+node.js+cors : even OPTIONS requests don't reach the server

Tags: node.js, curl, axios

I use the follow first middleware.Due to the token header, the first request to the server is OPTIONS request.For some reason, after reload both the client and server sides, SOMETIMES non-deterministically the request can reach to 'console.log("C")' and send status 200.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        console.log("A")

        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, token");
        res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', String(60 * 60 * 24 * 365));

        console.log("B")
        if(req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
          console.log("C")
          res.sendStatus(200);
          return res;
        }

        console.log("D")
        next();
      });
```

But subsequent GET or POST requests don't pass because of the message:

```
...has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

But if to use curl:

```
curl -I -X OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:3003/handler
```

I always get a normal response, which shows all the necessary headers for CORS

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, token
Access-Control-Max-Age: 31536000
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
ETag: W/"2-nOO9QiTIwXgNtWtBJezz8kv3SLc"
Date: Sat, 28 Mar 2020 07:24:18 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

With GET, POST requests in a similar way, everything is fine through the curl. But through the browser (using axios) it does not work. Again, it sounds crazy, but sometimes I correct / reload something, the request may even be successful, but when I pull the next handler, for example, / handler2, everything falls again.

Client:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:3003";
axios.defaults.headers.common["token"] = window.localStorage.token;

window.axios = axios;
axios.post("/user/handler", postData).then(...).catch(...);
```

**Please, don't say about app.use(cors()) or app.options(...) ))**

I'm sitting on it already God knows how much... tried everything possible. But I think the problem because of the client, but not the server...In the end, for curl it works.

Comment: In the cases when the browser logs a CORS error message in the console, you probably want to inspect the response in the Network pane in devtools—in particular, check the HTTP status code of the response, and confirm that it’s a 200 OK success response rather than a 4xx or 5xx error. If it’s not a 200 response but instead a 4xx or 5xx error, than it’s normal and expected that the browser will report a CORS error—but that’s because the server doesn’t add any additional headers to 4xx and 5xx errors. Even if it did, they’d still be 4xx and 5xx errors, and that’d be the real problem (not CORS).

Comment: @sideshowbarker , there is no status code in the response. But in the Response headers `HTTP/1.1 431 Request Header Fields Too Large
 ;Connection: close `( The server logs “A, B, C”, this means that status 200 has been sent)

Comment: Yeah so that 431 error is the real problem — though I don’t understand why that’d be happening only sometimes but not always.

Comment: @sideshowbarker , strange, but  've changed the header name from 'token' to 'Authorization' (capital letter) and it seems that works...hope it's deterministic))

Comment: No...the error appeared again

Answer (score 0):

My standard token size is 8 KB, but in Node.js --max-http-header-size is also 8 KB.
To fix this you need to write in package.json:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_OPTIONS=--max-http-header-size={YOUR HEADER SIZE} ts-node src/index.ts",
    "watch": "nodemon"
  },
```

(It was non-deterministic due to the fact that the token size could be slightly less than 8 KB sometimes, maybe)

Answer (score 0):

If the request is working fine with `curl` then I think the request header is being modified by some extensions in your browser.

**Try opening your client web application in incognito mode** `ctrl+shift+p` in mozilla firefox and `ctrl+shift+n` in Chrome browser and Test again.

You will get the same response as given by `cur` if the problem is due to any extension in your browser.